# Binary trees in racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

Hi the problem is I want to see if a binary tree is N

We call binary trees, where N be the number of numbers that will contain the list of all nodes. For example this is a binary tree 2:

`'((1 2) ((7 10) ((2 4) null null)) ((6 8) ((10 13) null null) null))`

And this is a binary tree 1:

`'(2- (7- (2 null null) (6 (5 null null) (11 null null))) (5 null (9 (4 null null) null)))`

I have this code:

```
(define (abN? arbol N) (                        

cond

[(= (length  (list-ref list 0)) N) "Arbol Binario N" "No es un arbol binario N" ]

[(= (number? (car list)) N) "Arbol Binario 1" "No es un arbol binario 1" ]

) 
)
```

Then put this in the console:

`(abN? '((1 2) ( (7 10) ( (2 4) null null) ) ((6 8) ((10 13) null null) null)) 2)`

and give me this error

```
car: contract violation
expected: pair?
given: #<procedure:list>
```

What I have been mistaken?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code, try this:

```
(define (abN? arbol N) 
  (cond
    [(number? (car arbol))
     (if (= N 1)
         "Arbol Binario 1"
         "No es un arbol binario 1")]
    [(list? (car arbol))
     (if (= (length (car arbol)) N)
         "Arbol Binario N" 
         "No es un arbol binario N")]
    [else (error "Dato de entrada incorrecto")]))
```

Explanation:

- The parameter is named `arbol`, but in your code you're referring to it as `list` (which by the way, is a built-in function). This is what's causing the error reported
- There's no need to use `list-ref` for accessing the first element of a list, use `car` instead
- You misunderstood how a `cond` expression works. Each condition evaluates to the last value of the expressions that follow it, if you need to test for further conditions you have to use an `if` or another `cond` inside, you seem to believe that each condition has an implicit `if-else` condition, and that's not correct
- First you must verify the type of the first element in the list, otherwise you run the risk of applying a list function over a number, which will result in an error
- Finally, it'll be easier to help you if you post the code in English. I can understand Spanish :P , but most people here won't.

It works as expected for the possible inputs:

```
(abN? '(1 ( (7 10) ( (2 4) null null) ) ((6 8) ((10 13) null null) null)) 1)
=> "Arbol Binario 1"
(abN? '(1 ( (7 10) ( (2 4) null null) ) ((6 8) ((10 13) null null) null)) 2)
=> "No es un arbol binario 1"
(abN? '((1 2) ( (7 10) ( (2 4) null null) ) ((6 8) ((10 13) null null) null)) 2)
=> "Arbol Binario N"
(abN? '((1 2) ( (7 10) ( (2 4) null null) ) ((6 8) ((10 13) null null) null)) 3)
=> "No es un arbol binario N"
(abN? '("bogus" ( (7 10) ( (2 4) null null) ) ((6 8) ((10 13) null null) null)) 3)
=> Unknown input
```